# moving file information to another file

Tags: text-processing

I have two files, `current_employee.txt` and `former_employee.txt`. When an employee resigns, I have to move their information from `current_employee.txt` to `former_employee.txt`. Please note I want to move the information of one person who is resigning.

the `current_employee.txt` is like

```
name:john
surname:James
salary:3000
department:finance

name:Paul
surname:Perez
salary:5000
department:inventory

name:Abel
surname:Wood
salary:4000
department:inventory
```

so i want to move Details of Paul....

I tried using cat current_employee.txt >former_employee.txt but it's moving all the employees details into former_employee.txt. I did all the researches but I didn't understand what I can do

Comment: Hi @TebelloSenekane - you don't really provide enough information for someone to help you... Are the "employee" details single line, multi-lined, in a special format or something else? Or is there one file per employee?  Are you happy with the data being appended to the end of former_employee.txt? or what is the requirement?

Comment: There is no example in the question. Please include a representative example of the `current_employee.txt` file (something that shold be usable as input, not a description of the content), containing both an employee that should not be removed and one that should (making it obvious what constitute an employee record within the file). Explain how the employee should be selected (based on name, ID etc.) and what should happen if a selection criteria matches multiple employees (if that is possible).

Comment: This is homework? Please show us what you've tried so far.

Comment: What have you researched or tried already? We will not do your work _for_ you, we only help out when you have tried, failed, and cannot figure out how or why it failed.

Comment: Hello Tebello,
If you have no idea where to start, you can take a look at awk and sed commands.
for example
awk /name:Paul/,/department/ current_employee.txt would print out the lines (including) name:Paul and department:inventory.
sed /name:Paul/,/^$/d current_employee.txt would print out the current_employee.txt without lines starting with name:Paul and ending with an empty line
You can append the output of awk to former_employee.txt and overwrite the current_employee.txt with output of sed
I don't know if there is one-command solution for what you need

Answer (score 1):

```bsh
awk -v name=Paul '
    BEGIN { RS=""; FS=":"; ORS="\n\n"; name = tolower(name) }
    tolower($2) == name { print; next }
    { print >(FILENAME ".new") }' current_employee.txt >>former_employee.txt
```

This would do several things, given a name on the command line (here `Paul`).  It would treat the input file, `current_employee.txt`, as a set of records that have a blank line between them (this is what `RS=""` does).  Each such record is divided into fields based on `:`, so that (assuming the `name` line is always first) `$1` is always the label `name` and `$2` is always the employee's first name.

It then sets the output record separator to a double newline to make sure there will always be an empty line at the end of each record that code outputs.  It also lower-cases the query name, just in case there upper/lower casing of the query string and data can't be trusted entirely to be correct (`john` is all lowercase already, for example).

If the lowercase name in the current record read from the input file is the same as our lowercase query string, then the whole record is outputted, and the program skips to the next line of input using `next`.

If the name in the current record is not what we are looking for, the record is also outputted, but to a file whose filename is the same as the input file's filename, with `.new` added to the end.

The output of the `awk` code is *appended* with `>>` to the file `former_employee.txt`.

This means that you'll get something like this when you run it:

```
$ ls
current_employee.txt
$ cat current_employee.txt
name:john
surname:James
salary:3000
department:finance

name:Paul
surname:Perez
salary:5000
department:inventory

name:Abel
surname:Wood
salary:4000
department:inventory
```

```
$ awk -v name=Paul '
    BEGIN { RS=""; FS=":"; ORS="\n\n"; name = tolower(name) }
    tolower($2) == name { print; next }
    { print >(FILENAME ".new") }' current_employee.txt >>former_employee.txt
$ ls
current_employee.txt      current_employee.txt.new  former_employee.txt
$ cat former_employee.txt
name:Paul
surname:Perez
salary:5000
department:inventory

$ cat current_employee.txt.new
name:john
surname:James
salary:3000
department:finance

name:Abel
surname:Wood
salary:4000
department:inventory
```

You may then use

```bsh
mv current_employee.txt.new current_employee.txt
```

to replace the old records of the current employee with the updated records.

---

Wrapping the above slightly unwieldy command in a shell script and giving it a bit more air:

```bsh
#!/bin/sh

for file in current_employee.txt former_employee.txt
do
    if [ -f "$file" ] && cp "$file" "$file-orig"; then
        printf 'Backed up %s as %s-orig\n' "$file" "$file"
    fi
done

awk -v name="$1" '
BEGIN {
    RS = ""
    FS = ":"
    ORS = "\n\n"
    name = tolower(name)
}

tolower($2) == name { print; next }

{ print >(FILENAME ".new") }' current_employee.txt >>former_employee.txt &&
mv current_employee.txt.new current_employee.txt
```

This script would back up the two files `current_employee.txt` and `former_employee.txt`, and then update them according to the name given as the first argument to the script.

You would typically use this script like

```
$ ./script Paul
```

Answer (score 0):

Using GNU awk utility v4.1.0 or later with the inplace option for editing files in-situ

```
# set input n output filenames
if=current_employee.txt
of=former_employee.txt

gawk -F: -i inplace -v n="John" '
  /^name:/&&tolower($2)==tolower(n),!NF{
    print >> OUT;next
  }1
' OUT="$of" "$if"
```

---

With the GNU line editor ed:

```
### set input n output filenames
if=current_employee.txt
of=former_employee.txt

### user defined function to make changes
fx() {
  ## unpack arguments
  n=$1

  ## escape any regex chars in name
  for e in \\ \[ ^ \$ . \* /;do
    n=${n//"$e"/\\"$e"}
  done

  ## make name case insensitive
  set -- {a..z}
  for UC in {A..Z}; do
    lc=$1; shift
    n=${n//[$lc$UC]/"[$lc$UC]"}
  done

  ## define the block which contains the name e.g., john
  block="?^name:${n}\$?;/^\$/"

  ## invoke ed editor to make changes
  ed -s "$if" <<eof
# add a dummy line to eof
a

.
# append block to former employee file
${block}W $of
# delete block from current employee file
${block}d
# take away the dummy line added
\$d
# save n quit from the current employee file
wq
eof
}

## and now invoke fx to make the changes in files
fx 'john'
### end
```

Now inspect the current and former employee text files to see the changes.